# Running python module in gedit embedded terminal

Tags: command-line, python, gedit

I'm new to python and i'm trying to run my first module but i can't do that through gedit embedded terminal the code i wrote is

```
def num(b):
    print("Give A Number")
    b = b +5
    print(b)
```

I managed to run it easily in IDLE but couldn't in gedit terminal i tried giving it `chmod +x`and used `./num.py` to run it also tried python `num.py`
but nothing happens the terminal just moves to a new line

Comment: are you in the right folder? can you try `python num.py`? is the name of your file `num.py` or something else? PS: welcome to python and to ask ubuntu!

Comment: Yeah i'm sure i'd that right

Comment: I asked three questions, you gave one answer.

Comment: That's an answer for your three questions

Comment: Your code (a) doesn't define `n` and (b) doesn't actually call the `num` function you just defined.

Comment: But why it worked well in IDLE and how to correct that ?

Comment: Add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of your `num.py` file. save your file in `home` folder, open terminal and run it by using `python3 num.py`

Comment: @KasiyA Didn't work :(

Comment: Did you get any error? if yes post in [question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/516764/edit)

Comment: No i get nothing at all the terminal just goes to a new line

Comment: Sorry i mistyped it here but it's b in my module

Comment: So you have run `python num.py` in terminal? And nothing happens? What happens in idle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is partially a summary of the comments, but here it is:

There is no way the code works in IDLE like it is pasted into your question: you do not call the function, and (thus) it has no argument as well.

To make it run from the terminal, your code (file) should at least include:

```
def num(b):
    print("Give a number ")
    b = b + 5
    print(b)

num(4)
```

Save it *including* language extension (`.py`) and run it by:

```
python3 /path/to/script
```

Alternatively, you can make it executable, and run it without `python3` in front, but then you *need* to add the shebang to your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def num(b):
    print("Give a number ")
    b = b + 5
    print(b)

num(4)
```

Then (if you made it executable), you can run it by:

```
/path/to/script
```

In that case, the language extension is not necessary.

If you are new to coding, I would say just use IDLE for writing, first testing and error correction, then use the terminal (like `gnome-terminal`) to check if all works as you planned.

As a side note: I am not sure what the script should do :)

I have the feeling you want something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def num(b):
    number = input("Give a number ")
    output = b + int(number)
    print("If I add "+str(b)+ ", it makes "+str(output))

num(4)
```

Then you would get a result like:

> Give a number

Then when you give a number:

> 7

After you press return, you get:

> If I add 4, it makes 11

Comment: It printed something but not what i wanted it should let the user give b a value then call num(b) and it prints b+5 it's a silly program i know but it was a tutorial for beginners that i'm following.. And thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AhmedGnedy added some information :)

Comment: +1 but I've noticed many (if not all) of your answers have `#!/usr/bin/env python3` shebang but I found (as a beginner) that `#!/usr/bin/env python` works and I wonder if that isn't the best future-proofing method as well as for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix #!/usr/bin/env python3 has been calling python 3 for ages on Ubuntu, while python calls python2, also since ages. Note that if you call a script by `python3 <script>`, the shebang plays no role, the interpreter is called directly from the command.

Comment: If the python2 shebang also works, it is because, coincidentally, the code works on both versions, which is not the case often. All my scripts are written and tested for python3.